# Failed to compile - Attempted import error: "Redirect'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-dom

I've been trying to sort out why I can't get my code to compile, since everything looks good, but I keep getting the error.

The error I am getting is

```bash
Failed to compile.
./src/pages/signup/SignupFrom.jsx
 Attempted import error: 'Redirect' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.
```

I've attached a copy of the code, and could use a bit of help, since react isn't my biggest strength and something I am still learning

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "negotiationlist",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongodb": "^5.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**SignupForm.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

require("dotenv").config();

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

const sendVerificationEmail = async (email, username) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
    },
  });

  const message = {
    from: "YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS",
    to: email,
    subject: "Verify your email address",
    text: `Hello ${username}, please click the following link to verify your email address: http://yourdomain.com/verify/${email}`,
  };

  await transporter.sendMail(message);
};

const SignupForm = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isSignedUp, setIsSignedUp] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!username || !email || !password) {
      setError("Please fill in all fields");
      return;
    }

    if (password.length < 8) {
      setError("Password must be at least 8 characters long");
      return;
    }

    const user = new User({
      username,
      email,
      password,
    });

    try {
      await user.save();
      await sendVerificationEmail(email, username);
      setIsSignedUp(true);
    } catch (error) {
      setError("An error occurred while signing up. Please try again later.");
    }
  };

  if (isSignedUp) {
    return <Redirect to="/success" />;
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Username"
        value={username}
        onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={email}
        onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
      />
      {error && <p>{error}</p>}
      <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignupForm;
```

Comment: If the answer bellow helped, please consider mark your question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use `redirect` rather than `Redirect` (lower case the first `R`)

See [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect)